# What does "Further bulletins as events warrant" mean?

Tags: expressions

I came across the following expression, "Further bulletins as events warrant," when reading Calvin and Hobbes comic strip.  I googled it but cannot find out what it means.  I just don't understand the structure of it.  Here, "warrant" is a verb?

Comment: Could you link us to the original strip so we can get the context right?

Comment: haha came here for the exact same strip. Here's the link: http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2016/10/22

Comment: It's radio/TV speak.  It means "We will resume our regular programming but will break in with any new news about the ongoing situation."

Comment: Thank you so much for paraphrasing the expression, which made it easier for me to understand what Calvin means by using the expression!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *warrant* is a verb here, in the meaning of *justify* or *necessitate*. Further bulletins will be issued if and when required by future events.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. Now I clearly understand why Calvin uses the expression when leaving as well as the meaning of the expression!